# How to deploy my Rails app to a shared host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shared-hosting

I have been chipping away at this for the last couple of days but it has become quite frustrating. My web host is "JustHost" and I have a shared hosting service. I have found this translates directly to "strips you of all privileges," when it comes to trying to set up the deployment on the server.

I thought I had found some really good tutorials that might help me to get my environment set up (I tried to Follow Rob McLarty's blogs on [How to setup a Production Server](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-production-server-for-rails-4) and [How to Deploy a Rails App](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano) as best as I could). The problem that I found is that I couldn't/didn't need to install any of the things recommended, and when it came time to try to set things up I didn't have permission over the files that were recommended to modify or I didn't have permission to use the commands that were needed.

Naturally I can see why this would be important on a shared host. It would be silly if each individual on the host could restart an apache server willy nilly.

Regardless, I have found this to be the problem with most of the research into getting this deployment up and running. Simply put,  most of the things that are recommended I don't have permission to access.

Does anyone know how to setup a deployment on an environment that is so restrictive? Even some resources, or a simple "you are thinking about this way too hard" to point me in the right direction would be really really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend OpenShift as a platform for deploying your rails app on a shared environment. It gives you the option to start for free with a small amount of resources in the server and gives you the ability of starting up everything you need at first like relational or NoSQL databases, loadbalancers, cache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a simple setup formula, For a shared host ROR Deployment Found a good reference : [REFERENCE LINK](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails) this will help to deploy ROR App on a shared host.(some modules may not be allowed on a shared server environment. You may have to go for a VPS to meet all the requirements).